# How to receive emails directly to a Brother MFC-j6510dw

Tags: email, pop3, brother-printer

I have a Brother MFC-J6510DW, a wireless multi-function printer.  After upgrading the firmware on it, I was able to send emails directly from it by inputting my internet provider's email server settings.

Is it possible to receive emails directly to the printer and have them print out automatically as soon as an email arrives?

The printer has settings for both SMTP (which work fine) and POP3, so I assume it could receive just like it can send.  It sends emails but will not print out any emails sent to it.  Interestingly, it does say "receiving", as I have set it to poll for newly sent emails from the server every 2 minutes, but so far, nothing prints out or shows on the screen.

Any Ideas would be most welcome

Answer (score 1):

This model can send and print emails. It cannot download them, it only reads them from the server and then prints (so it's not viewable on the LCD of the printer for example)!

If your email is not on the server, then there is nothing to print.

Also, it prints ALL emails on the server, you cannot specify which one(s).

My guess is you're using a POP3 client (like Outlook/Thunderbird) and you're downloading all emails to your machine and then removing them from the server (this is automatic and can be configured in your email client) meaning no emails are left on the server.

---

To print all emails on the server (just for your email account obviously):

Ensure your firmware/drivers are [up to date](http://tinyurl.com/7jz9bdv).

Look under Protocols section under the Network tab.

More details (most of which you know, but I include all for fullness):

After updated, log into the Brother machine's web management
use 'access' as the password
click on the network tab and then protocols
select pop3 / smtp
advanced settings
Set your pop 3 info, address, mailbox, pass etc...
Select the FAX tab
Select email receive
Update the poll time.

If there are any emails on the server, it will automatically print them all at that time. It will not delete or touch your emails, so, if your email was not removed from the server and your poll was set to 10 minutes, it would mean the same email would print every 10 minutes.

If this is not the case, you will need to talk to Brother directly.

---

More details about why POP is used on your machine

POP3 can be used for "[Pop before SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP_before_SMTP)" (which is just an authentication method and has nothing to do with downloading emails)

Read your manual page 55 for more detail or read this [generic Brother manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Brother%20International/MFC-J6510DW/Manual/117012?page=59)

Comment: Then why does it  polli for emails if it cannot receive?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me David,

I have updated the firmware to the very latest,

And I have set all pop3 settings as per my email providers webpage: http://help.optuszoo.com.au/help/dsl/connected

Polls every minute and the screen says receiving, 

 I have just checked and it does say when I confirm the pop3  settings it runs a send receive test, send passes fine receiving failes with a user name password error, I dont see why it would be  diffrent to my send un and password, hmm any ideas?

Comment: @Ben I would check that your settings are indeed correct. Create a new email account in your email client (Outlook/Thunderbird) and enter the details manually.